# How to find logged in user from Windows Registry?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

am developing a windows store 8.1 app using C# and xaml.

In my app I want to find logged in user name from Windows Registry.

How can I get that from C# code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find the user name in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Volatile Environment\USERNAME`.
However, I'm pretty sure you won't be able to access this from a Windows Store App.

I'd suggest looking at the [UserInformation.GetDomainNameAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.userprofile.userinformation.getdomainnameasync.aspx) method or other methods in the [UserInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.userprofile.userinformation.aspx) class instead.

Comment: Thanks Hans..Great help
lets say if i logged in with the email which is something_someone@example.com
using this how can i get something_someone from something_someone@example.com
how to get the logged in email from windows registry?

Comment: @SanthoshKumar Sorry, not exactly sure what you mean, but I'd suggest that you try to check what information you can get from the `UserInformation` class by looking at it in the debugger and see if it contains what you need.